# Return generator instead of list of locations from a 2d Array

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I was working on a game yesterday where I had to traverse a 2-D array and find the location of any cells marked "d" (where cells are represented as either "-" for blank or "d" for dirty).

I did this using two for-loops:

```
def find_dirty_cells(board):

  dirty_cells = []
    for enum, row in enumerate(board):
      for enumrow, cell in enumerate(row):
        if cell == 'd':
          dirty_cells.append((enum, enumrow))

  return dirty_cells
```

But then I thought it might be better to build a generator object and return that instead, so I wrote this:

```
def find_dirty_cells(board):
  return ((enum, enumrow) for enumrow, cell in enumerate(row) for enum, row in enumerate(board) if cell == 'd')
```

But the second gives me incorrect data in response (i.e., it doesn't find the 'd' cells). There must be something simple I am overlooking that makes the second not equal to the first, but I can't see it. The real question I tried to solve is this: is there an easy way to make my first attempt return a generator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to list your `for` loops in the same order you nest them:

```
def find_dirty_cells(board):
    return ((enum, enumrow) for enum, row in enumerate(board) for enumrow, cell in enumerate(row) if cell == 'd')
```

You had swapped the `enumerate(board)` and `enumerate(row)` loops, which would only work if there was a global `row` variable still available in your session or in your module.

It may be easier in this case to just use a generator *function* instead of a generator expression, by using `yield` instead of `dirty_cells.append()`:

```
def find_dirty_cells(board):
    for enum, row in enumerate(board):
        for enumrow, cell in enumerate(row):
            if cell == 'd':
                yield enum, enumrow
```

This will have the exact same effect but is perhaps more readable.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation. I knew something simple was tripping me up and I guess I'm still getting confused by comprehensions. I agree that the yield version is more readable. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

To cleanly convert your original function into a generator, what you want is the [`yield`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement) statement, rather than the `return` (or in your particular case, rather than the `append`). I'd prefer this version to the generator expression version, because the original is vastly more [readable](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

```
def find_dirty_cells(board):
    for enum, row in enumerate(board):
        for enumrow, cell in enumerate(row):
            if cell == 'd':
                yield (enum, enumrow)
```

Answer (score 1):

The is a straightforward way to do this using `numpy.ndenumerate()`:

```
from numpy import ndenumerate
find_dirty_cells = lambda a: (i for i,v in ndenumerate(a) if v=='d')
```

and this would work for an array with more than 2 dimensions as well.